# Apple CalDav server behaves erratically when asking for expanded retrieval of recurring event

Tags: icloud, icalendar, caldav

I am using CALDAV:calendar-multiget REPORT for expanded retrieval of recurring event.
The request looks like:

```
curl -X REPORT \
  https://caldav.icloud.com:443/1234567890/calendars/work/ \
  -H 'authorization: Basic XXXXXX' \
  -H 'content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8' \
  -d '<c:calendar-multiget xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
    <d:prop>
        <c:calendar-data>
          <c:expand start="20171201T000000Z" end="20180101T000000Z"/>
        </c:calendar-data>
    </d:prop>
    <d:href>/1234567890/calendars/work/ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL.ics</d:href>
</c:calendar-multiget>'
```

Sometimes the Apple server gives expanded events in the response but sometimes it gives only the master event without expansion.

Am I doing anything wrong here?
Has anyone else faced this behaviour?